# How do I best remove all invalid non name characters in PHP (for any common language)?

Tags: php, validation

I want to not just validate that it's a proper name, but remove any characters that don't belong. I know preg_replace is what I'm looking for, but what's the regex to test for english, latin, asian, and other languages?

My database uses utf_general_ui for text fields, but I want to strip out stuff that isn't used in names (like most special characters).

Examples:

はやお　みやざき

Michael O'Doul, Jr.

Eiður Smári Guðjohnsen

Comment: This task is impossible. How do you want to decide what characters are "valid" inside a "name"? As a general rule of thumb: try not to "enhance" data entered by a user. Usually the user knows his name better than you _guess_ it might be.

Comment: I want to remove non-valid characters. I don't see how that's a bad thing. I suppose I could just pick the more common special characters if no one knows a better way.

Comment: I repeat the question: what are "valid" / "non-valid" characters?

Comment: Numbers aren't used in names. Neither are most special characters from 1 through 9

Comment: Yes, those are _some_ characters one might call "non-valid" (though I am not actually sure about that, just think of "King Henry IV" ...). Also I do not see the difference between what you call "numbers" and the "special characters from 1 through 9"... Anyways, the problem is: things get complicated when you consider not only your own language (or better culture). The unicode alphabeth is _huge_. No one knows how all those millions of characters are used...

Comment: So it sounds like my best bet is to manually specify a list of invalid characters.

Comment: Absolutely, that is an option. But as said: be _very_ careful as what to consider "invalid", you might frustrate users otherwise by changing their name... Usually what is done is to strip all _whitespace_ characters (trimming) and that's it. Since usually users see themselves when they have made a typo when entering their name.

Comment: With `\p{L}` you can select all Unicode Letters, in every Language, why don't use this?

Comment: Because I don't want to allow non-name characters like numbers. There are many valid unicode characters that aren't names.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for checking, but I don't know how to remove wrong characters:

```
<?php

    function valid($value)
    {
        return (strlen(preg_replace('/\p{L}|[., \'　]/u',"",$value)) == 0);
    }

    function showBoolean($bool)
    {
        if($bool)
        {
         echo "true";
         }
        else
        {
         echo "false";
         }
    }

    showBoolean(valid("やお　みやざき"));
    showBoolean(valid("Michael O'Doul, Jr."));
    showBoolean(valid("Eiður Smári Guðjohnsen"));
    showBoolean(valid("やお　みやざき ?$"));
    showBoolean(valid("Michael O'Doul, Jr. %$"));
    showBoolean(valid("Eiður Smári Guðjohnsen \""));

?>
```

Result:

```
true
true
true
false
false
false
```